# Why I am getting error: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." in asp.net core 5.0 web api

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

Here is my code:

```
var results = (from indexing in _dbContext.MasterOrder.AsEnumerable()
                           join p in _dbContext.Product.AsEnumerable() on indexing.Id equals p.ProductIndex
                           join b in _dbContext.ProductX.AsEnumerable() on indexing.Id equals bl.ProductXIndex
                           where (indexing.Type == "XX" || indexing.Type == "YY") &&
                           indexing.PublishDate >= cur_date && indexing.Status != "DRAFT"
                                              && terms.Any(term =>
                                                  indexing.ProductName.Contains(term)
                                               || indexing.Description.ToLower().Contains(term)
                                               || indexing.Category.ToLower().Contains(term)
                                               || indexing.PString.ToLower().Contains(term)
                                               || indexing.IString.ToLower().Contains(term))
                                               && (IProducts.Count > 0 ? IProducts.Any(iproduct => indexing.IString.Contains(iproduct.name)) : true)
                                               && (CProducts.Count > 0 ? CProducts.Any(cproduct => indexing.CString.Contains(cproduct.name)) : true)
                           select new Response()
                           {
                               Image = Service.ImageUrl(indexing.Type, indexing.Image),
                               Link = Service.Url(indexing.Type, indexing.Url),
                               Title = indexing.ProductNameName,
                               Description = indexing.Description,
                               PublishDate = Convert.ToDateTime(indexing.PublishDate).ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy"),
                               Type = indexing.Type
                           }
                           ).Skip(pageSize * (pageIndex - 1)).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

here terms, IProducts and CProducts are string arrays having search texts to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `AsEnumerable()` runs a query and opens a DataReader.  You can't have all those DataReaders open at the same time.  To fix, remove all the `AsEnumerable()` calls.

Comment: Hi @David but removing `AsEnumerable()` gives *The LINQ expression* error and suggests to rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Comment: Yes.  So do that.